# Smallest group which is $(2,5,5)$-generated.

Tags: group-theory, riemann-surfaces

A finite group $G$ is said to be $(2,5,5)$-generated if there are elements $x,y,z \in G$ with $|x| = 2, |y| = |z| = 5$ so that $G = \langle x, y, z \rangle$ and $xyz = 1$. An example of $(2,5,5)$-generated group is a non-abelian group of order $80$, which is solvable. Are there any example of groups of smaller size?

Comment: Do you have a link about this group of order $80$ that it is $(2,5,5)$-generated? Such a text might mention more references (for example like in [this book](https://books.google.at/books?id=GKUBky1C0VEC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=(2,5,5)-generated+groups&source=bl&ots=dmfxX_z6Eh&sig=ACfU3U1HNgRyCUlWrhSpw2bSPpDoHFUt4A&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix4emZiZXoAhUM2KQKHXSbCUYQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=(2%2C5%2C5)-generated%20groups&f=false))

Comment: The same book Pg.50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A_5$ of order $60$ is $(2,5,5)$-generated with, for example, $x=(1, 2)(3, 4)$, $y=(1, 4, 2, 3, 5)$, $z=(1, 5, 4, 2, 3)$ (that's composing left to right; swap $y$ and $z$ if you prefer to compose right to left).

Since a $(2,5,5)$-group has order divisible by $10$ and does not have a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup, 60 is the smallest possible order.

All other groups of order 60 are solvable and have a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup, so $80$ is the smallest possible order of a solvable $(2,5,5)$-generated group.

Comment: Actually $(2,5,5)$-generation of $G$ require $G/[G,G]$ is either trivial, or cyclic of order $5$. Then for $80$ is the smallest order for the second case and $60$ is least for the "perfect" case. Thanks a lot, Derek.

Comment: Another interesting comment: the $(2,5,5)$-generation and the fact $[G, G] = C^4_2$ of the group of order $80$ can be deduced (without GAP). Let $\varphi$ be a ${\mathbb{F}}_2$-linear automorphism of order $5$ on ${\mathbb{F}}^4_2$. Then $G = {\mathbb{F}}_2 : \langle \varphi \rangle$. In this situation, for any $0 \neq v \in {\mathbb{F}}^4_2$ we have $v \varphi$ has order $5$ and $G = \langle v, \varphi \rangle$.